# change select to select2 dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a select dropdown initially when loading a web page. On clicking the dropdown I need to change that to select2 dropdown. However, instead of single click, double click converts the select to select2 dropdown. Can anyone help me where I am going wrong? Here is the code.

```
$('#select_id').on('click', function(){
    $(this).select2().select2('open');
});
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hwsjz56o/5/

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a snippet or jsfiddle would do

Comment: here is the link to jsfiddle. [https://jsfiddle.net/hwsjz56o/5/]

Comment: What's the problem? When I click once on the select it opens and converts it so select2

Comment: On clicking once, i am only seeing a normal select  and clicking again is only enabling the select2. Can you please a bit cautious while clicking? (whether single or double click)

Comment: It does work if you click, but you shouldn't click and drag outside the box or else it won't work. That's a normal behavior, why are you looking to do that?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I am making a perfect click

Comment: A perfect click works fine for me on latest version of chrome.

Comment: Thanks @IslamElshobokshy, I think it is the browser issue. It is working fine with firefox too.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Feel free to delete the question if there's nothing more you could add to it.